# Has a flaw been found about the lies in Gone Girl?

Tags: gone-girl, gillian-flynn

In the book Gone Girl, at least one character uses elaborate lies to get their way. (Those who have read the book know who and what; for others, I don't think that much is a big spoiler, but I'll be happy to edit.)

Have readers found a flaw in those lies, that would derail that part of the plot?

Comment: Do you have reason to think there might be? If there is something you think creates a plot hole, it would make a better question if you ask specifically about that.

Comment: @Spagirl: The scheme of lies the book describes is so complicated that it would be somewhat surprising if there wasn't a hole in it somewhere. I expect that this motivated the question.

Comment: Well, my main motivation is such. Another character says that the lies I'm referring to in my post build a perfect fabrication and the liar is going to get away with it. Since it strongly clashes with my sense of ethics (and in the century-old tradition of trying, and generally failing, to outwit mystery writers), my immediate reaction was, "Oh, YEAH?". I assume other people have had the same, and may have published their findings.  [This question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/14453/is-this-a-plot-hole-in-gone-girl?rq=1) may be such an attempt.

Comment: In other words, I have less reason than hope to think there might be.